# Object doesn't contain a definition for "Text"

Tags: c#, winforms

So I just learned Microsoft Visual. I tried to use label and trying to set a text using the event handler, but i got an error in the line `this.lblText.Text`, more specifically in the "Text", could someone please let me know how to solve it? I don't really understand about C#

this is the code

```
namespace Praktikum1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private object lblText;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblText.Text = "Belajar Pemrograman Visual C#";

        }
    }
}
```

the error is in = `this.lblText`, the `Text`,

Comment: somehow you have lblText as 'object' rather than a real Label control. How did you get that?

Comment: I wish I know, got the code from the module, so I've got really confused now

Comment: If you want a `Label`, add one to form in the designer. Don't just copy code form the internet or wherever that uses objects that you don't have. I'm confident that any tutorial that tells you to use a `Label` would have told you to create a `Label` in the first place.

Comment: Tags are important for other users to quickly get what a question is all about. Your question is definitely not about Visual C++, so I removed this tag for you and replaced it by the more appropriate "winforms" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see to have added lblText by hand here

```
 private object lblText;
```

if generated by the form designer it would be declared as

```
private Label lblText;
```

You say the 'module' did this, I dont know what that means. Also its impossible to know if lblText is really a label or not.

If it is then this will work

```
((Label)this.lblText).Text = "Belajar Pemrograman Visual C#";
```

ie - casting the `object` to the `Label` type

Answer (score 0):

You should `create the label` and then `change its text`:

```
Label testLBL = new Label();
this.Controls.Add(testLBL);
testLBL.Text = "testLBL";
```

Or add the `label to the form through the toolbox`(from designer) and set text.